# Access Violation on FObjectFinder

Tags: c++, crash, unreal-engine4

I got a problem with my project in unreal. I wrote some code about a month ago and it worked fine until yesterday when the editor started crashin on launch.
I get this error message in the log:

```
[2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: === Critical error: ===
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: Fatal error!
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x000008d0
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000002548206A UE4Editor-Landscape.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000000B927D45 UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000000B95BF0E UE4Editor-Engine.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000145DE8FD UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000001469DABC UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146B5259 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146B4774 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:731][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146CB0C3 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146D5A3A UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146D51B2 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000F7A72E21 UE4Editor-Lyfe_Game.dll!ConstructorHelpersInternal::FindOrLoadObject<UParticleSystem>() [c:\program files\epic games\ue_4.18\engine\source\runtime\coreuobject\public\uobject\constructorhelpers.h:35]
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000F7A7314F UE4Editor-Lyfe_Game.dll!UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell::UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell() [c:\users\megapoort\desktop\lyfe\lyfe_game\source\lyfe_game\private\compound_particlecomponent_cell.cpp:30]
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000144605CD UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x0000000014698696 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000145E3EC4 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000F7A6B41D UE4Editor-Lyfe_Game.dll!ACompoundCloud_Cell::ACompoundCloud_Cell() [c:\users\megapoort\desktop\lyfe\lyfe_game\source\lyfe_game\private\compoundcloud_cell.cpp:64]
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000144605CD UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146D91B0 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000146BB41F UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x0000000014462547 UE4Editor-CoreUObject.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000149CE6C0 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x0000000014C22282 UE4Editor-Core.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000004489F60D UE4Editor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000004489F91E UE4Editor-Projects.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66F7F71 UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66FC4EC UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66F525A UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B66F54AA UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B6702379 UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x00000000B6703D57 UE4Editor.exe!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000005ED03034 KERNEL32.DLL!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000005F271431 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: [Callstack] 0x000000005F271431 ntdll.dll!UnknownFunction []
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:732][  0]LogWindows: Error: 
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:750][  0]LogExit: Executing StaticShutdownAfterError
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:751][  0]LogWindows: FPlatformMisc::RequestExit(1)
 [2018.06.25-20.39.29:751][  0]Log file closed, 06/25/18 22:39:29
```

`compoundcloud_cell.cpp:64` is where I create a default subobject for the actor. In its constructor (`compound_particlecomponent_cell.cpp:30`) The code that crashes the editor is located.
The line that is logged here is:

```
 auto psAsset = ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UParticleSystem>(TEXT("ParticleSystem'/Game/ParticleSystems/PS_CompoundCloud_SingleCelled.PS_CompoundCloud_SingleCelled'"));
```

The code snippet where I create the component looks like this:+

```
std::string center = "CenterSystem";
    UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell* temp = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCompound_ParticleComponent_Cell>(center.c_str());
    particles.Add(temp);
    RootComponent = temp;
```

Has anybody got any idea why this might suddenly cause crashes? I've worked on the particle system a lot lately but the name is still the same so I thought it shouldn't affect the object finder.

It would be fantastic if someone could help me with this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so it was nothing to do with the FObject finder or the particle system itself.
There were some unconnected nodes in the material used in the particle system.
Check your materials!

Answer (score 0):

Kinda supit but I thought I might try updating from 4.18 to 4.19 and it actually fixed the problem. So if you have a similar problem: Try upgrading.

Edit:
It worked for a limited amout of time.

By now I tried to load particle systems in other classes in the constructor and I get an access violation every single time.

Edit 2:
Still no answer. This has been slowing down the project for so long. If anyone wants to have a look:
https://github.com/GameAboutThings/Lyfe